# What maximum energy can be stored in a gluon field flux tube

Tags: standard-model, quarks

Question is as clear as stated in title.

What is the maximum energy that can be stored in a gluon field flux tube without production of an quark anti-quark pair?

And how much it usually store in a meson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string with heavy $Q$ quarks at the endpoints breaks by forming $Q\bar{q}$ mesons. Taking $c$ quarks for illustration we have $\bar{Q}Q\to \bar{Q}q+\bar{q}Q\to D+\bar{D}$, where $D$ is a D-meson. Using $m_D=1.85$ GeV, and $m_c=1.29$ GeV, I can store $2(m_D-m_c)=1.1$ GeV in the string. With a string tension of 1 GeV/fm, this corresponds to a length of about 1fm.

For detailed studies, see here  http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/0505012.

Comment: And how much it usually stores in a meson?

Comment: In a heavy quark meson, this is a well defined question. The string stores (string tension)x(mean $\bar{Q}Q$ separation). This is something like 200 MeV in a J/psi. In light mesons, the question does not make sense, because light quark strings break very easily.