# How far can we separate two bound quarks?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, estimation, confinement

If we try to separate two quarks bound into a meson or a hadron, the energy in the gluon field eventually will be large enough to spawn a quark-antiquark pair.

How far can we stretch that gluon field before it "snaps"? What's the average distance? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: About one fermi, see here: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/0505012 (e.g. Fig.22)

Answer (score 12):

From lattice calculations (see [String Tension of
Quark-Anti-Quark Pairs in
Lattice QCD](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dtaylor/Dissertation.pdf)) it has been found that the string tension of the quarks, in the case of pions, is given by
$$
\sqrt{\sigma}\sim460\ \mathrm{MeV}
$$
which is equivalent to a length of $\sim 2.7\ \mathrm{fermi}$.

In the case of the charmonium ($\bar c c$), the tension (see [Charmonium potential from full lattice QCD](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.0888v2.pdf)) is close to
$$
\sqrt{\sigma}\sim394\ \mathrm{MeV}
$$
that is, a lenght of $3.1\ \mathrm{fermi}$.

For a bottomonium state ($\bar b b$), the best estimate I've found (see [Bottomonium states versus recent experimental observations in the
QCD-inspired potential model](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.0960v1.pdf)) is
$$
\sqrt\sigma\sim 410\ \mathrm{MeV}
$$
i.e., $3\ \mathrm{fermi}$.

Comment: This number is too large, see my answer here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/238218/what-maximum-energy-can-be-stored-in-a-gluon-field-flux-tube/238223#238223

Comment: @Thomas Where did you get the $1\ \mathrm {GeV/fm}$ value? You can see in my links (which are more recent than yours) that the LQCD results are closer to $400\ \mathrm{MeV/fm}$...

Comment: (460 MeV)^2=1 GeV/fm

Comment: @Thomas welp, according to [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=460+MeV+to+fermi) its more like $2.7\ \mathrm{fm}$.

Comment: (460 MeV)^2 = (460 MeV)/(200 MeV*fm) = 460 MeV * 2.3/fm = 1 GeV/fm

Comment: @Thomas there is some weird algebra going on there :P (perhaps a square is missing?) anyway, I don't see how any of this is relevant to the question or my answer (and in any case, any possible result for this is kind of questions is an estimate, so it's perfectly reasonable for you and me to get two different results, mine twice as large as yours)

Comment: 1) Since string breaking scale is known in GeV, we have to convert string tension from energy squared to energy/distance. No mystery here. 2) There is a weird error in woflram alpha. 460 MeV=2.3/fm not 2.7/fm, but this is indeed no big deal. 3) String breaking scale is not uncertain  by a factor of three, it is uncertain by (10-15)%, see the arxive preprint I cite.

Comment: @Thomas 1) you wrote (460 MeV)^2 = (460 MeV)/(200 MeV$*$fm) when you probably meant (460 MeV)^2 = (460 MeV)$\color{red}{{}^2}$/(200 MeV$*$fm) (whatever, not important) 2) yep, weird huh?. 3) a "scale" is always uncertain by more than a $10-15\%$, because it's a *scale* after all. Again, your paper disagrees with mine, so it's pointless for us to reference them: I too can say "see the preprint I cite", and wouldn't be any more correct/wrong than you...

Comment: 1) Yes. 3) You cite a paper for the string tension (correct, of course); I show how to convert this to a string breaking distance (different number, but well determined), The paper I cite confirms that this is the right number, because they compute BOTH the string tension and the string breaking distance.

Comment: @Thomas Oh, now I see what you meant! sorry for that, I just misunderstood you. It thought you were saying that the string tension was off by a factor of two, not the breaking distance. I just converted the tension to distance, neglecting the mass/energy details, and that's why I said that the number was an estimate.  But you're right that your calculation is more accurate (though I still think that *any* possible answer for this question is kind of uncertain by at least a factor of two, so to some extent the details *can* be neglected: we are talking QM here, so the "distance" *is* uncertain)

Comment: The QCD string has heavy quarks at its endpoints, so the string length is defined up to an uncertainty $1/m_b\sim 0.05$ fm.

Answer (score 7):

From the [HyperPhysics site on Quarks](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/particles/quark.html#c6):

It is postulated that it may actually increase with distance at the rate of about **1 GeV per fermi**. A free quark is not observed because by the time the separation is on an observable scale, the energy is far above the pair production energy for quark-antiquark pairs. For the U and D quarks the masses are 10s of MeV so pair production would occur for distances **much less than a fermi**. You would expect a lot of mesons (quark-antiquark pairs) in very high energy collision experiments and that is what is observed.

From what I can gather, the actual increase in energy per fermi is not known to a high accuracy because the range is so incredibly small. Considering that the strong nuclear force is only able to participate in interactions at distances of less than $10^{-15}$ m it is understandable that no exact numbers exist for the maximum separation two quarks can have.

Comment: Check. But you pop hadrons out of the vacuum, so, let's say a π⁰, so then very crudely 0.135 fermis.... more than a tenth of a fermi, if needs be.